# How to get mean of nonzero elements by row, varying which columns are used by a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, boolean, aggregate

Suppose I have the following data table:

```
  tempmat=matrix(c(1,1,0,4,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,4, 0,0,1,4, 0,0,0,5),5,4,byrow=T)
  tempmat=rbind(rep(0,4),tempmat)
  tempmat=data.table(tempmat)
  names(tempmat)=paste0('prod1vint',1:4)
```

Which looks like:

```
       prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4
1:          0          0          0          0
2:          1          1          0          4
3:          1          0          0          4
4:          0          1          0          4
5:          0          0          1          4
6:          0          0          0          5
```

I want to define a new column, TN, that takes the mean row-wise in the following fashion.

1. For each row, find the first nonzero element going left to right.
2. Then, find the mean of all nonzero elements to the RIGHT of that.

The output should be:

```
   prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4   TN
1:          0          0          0          0   NA
2:          1          1          0          4   2.5
3:          1          0          0          4   4
4:          0          1          0          4   4
5:          0          0          1          4   4 
6:          0          0          0          5   NA
```

The NA's arise because in 1: there are no nonzero elements, and in 6: there are no nonzero elements to the right of the first nonzero element.

Comment: maybe: `tempmat[, TN := mean(unlist(.SD)[abs(.SD)>0][-1L]), by=tempmat[, seq_len(.N)]]`? but if u need speed, you might want to consider Rcpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `melt`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
TN <- melt(tempmat[, rid := seq_len(.N)], id.var = 'rid')[, 
    {i1 <- cumsum(value) > 0
    mean(na_if(value[i1][-1], 0), na.rm = TRUE)}, rid]$V1
tempmat[, TN := TN][]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tempmat %>% 
   mutate(TN = pmap(., ~ c(...) %>% 
           keep(., cumsum(.) > 0) %>%
           tail(-1) %>% 
           na_if(0) %>%
           mean(na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Or another option is to transpose the dataset and then do the colwise operation

```
t(tempmat) %>%
    as.data.frame %>% 
    summarise_all(list(~ mean(na_if(.[cumsum(.) > 0], 0)[-1],
          na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    unlist %>%
    mutate(tempmat, TN = .)
```

---

Or using a vectorized approach

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- rowCumsums(as.matrix(tempmat)) > 0
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m1, 'first'))] <- FALSE
rowMeans(na_if(tempmat * NA^!m1, 0), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
apply(tempmat, 1, FUN = function(x) 
      mean(na_if(x[cumsum(x) > 0], 0)[-1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` row-wise we can first find out indices in the row which are not 0. Then calculate the `mean` for non-zero values `if` there is atleast one non-zero value and the non-zero value is not present in the last column `else` return `NA`.

```
tempmat$TN <- apply(tempmat, 1, function(x) {
           inds <- x != 0
           if (any(inds) & which.max(inds) != length(x)) 
             mean(Filter(function(f) f > 0, x[(which.max(inds) + 1) : length(x)]))
           else  
              NA
            })

tempmat
#   prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4  TN
#1:          0          0          0          0  NA
#2:          1          1          0          4 2.5
#3:          1          0          0          4 4.0
#4:          0          1          0          4 4.0
#5:          0          0          1          4 4.0
#6:          0          0          0          5  NA
```

Comment: Interesting, do you think that there may be anything more efficient than an apply approach? I believe apply doesn't scale particularly well.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over columns, only operating when non-zero and after the first non-zero col in that row:

```
DT[, `:=`(n = 0L, s = 0, v = NA_real_)]
for (k in sprintf("prod1vint%s", 1:4)) 
  DT[get(k) != 0, `:=`(s = s + (n > 0)*get(k), n = n + 1L)]
DT[n > 1L, v := s/(n - 1)][]

   prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4 n s   v
1:          0          0          0          0 0 0  NA
2:          1          1          0          4 3 5 2.5
3:          1          0          0          4 2 4 4.0
4:          0          1          0          4 2 4 4.0
5:          0          0          1          4 2 4 4.0
6:          0          0          0          5 1 0  NA
```

Because this is vectorized, doesn't coerce to matrix and operates selectively, I expect that it is pretty efficient. The `get` part is awkward. but could be avoided like...

```
DT[, `:=`(n = 0L, s = 0, v = NA_real_)]
for (k in sprintf("prod1vint%s", 1:4)){ 
  expr = substitute(DT[k != 0, `:=`(s = s + (n > 0)*k, n = n + 1L)], list(k = as.name(k)))
  eval(expr)
}
DT[n > 1L, v := s/(n - 1)][]
```